# Fatal error 11 when loading a picture in imageview

Tags: android

I want to display a picture on the initial activity in my android app so I edited the xml of it to look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nyork1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/button_register"

        />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/button_login"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

With a tag for the image view which links to a picture stored in the drawable folders called nyork1 in png format. I copied the picture to the drawable hdpi, mdpi and ldpi just to make sure. But when I try to start the app, I get a Fatal Signal 11 which I don't really see why.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. Seems like the image was too big for android. Had to re scale it.